# Getting specific values from api response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I send an Ajax request to a PHP file which sends a CURL request to an API and then return the results.

The PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.example.com?country=usa');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = array('result' => $result);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Javascript/jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(typeof(data.result));
        console.log(data.result);
    }
});
```

The type of the result is `string` and the result looks like:

`{"results":[{"code2":"093","code1":"NY","lng":-73.9395687,"name1":"New York","lat":42.8142432}]}`

How to get the `lng` and `lat` from that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the proxy is returning the response from the third party API as a JSON encoded string you need to manually deserialise it. You can do that by using `JSON.parse()`. Then you can access the objects within the `results` array by index. Try this:

```js
var data = {
  result: '{"results":[{"code2":"093","code1":"NY","lng":-73.9395687,"name1":"New York","lat":42.8142432}]}'
}

// inside your AJAX callback:
var obj = JSON.parse(data.result);
var lat = obj.results[0].lat;
var lng = obj.results[0].lng;

console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
```

Comment: What if I want to get the same values with PHP?

Comment: I'm not a PHP dev, but I believe that you'd need to use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to deserialise the response before accessing the relevant properties

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {"results":[{"code2":"093","code1":"NY","lng":-73.9395687,"name1":"New York","lat":42.8142432}]}
console.log(data.results[0].lat);
console.log(data.results[0].lng);
```

`data.results` is array therefore use `[0]` to get first element of Array:

```
data.result[0]
```

And then get contents of first element:

```
data.result[0].lat
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.result[0].lat);
        console.log(data.result[0].lng);
    }
});
```